# Django tests don't raise integrity error for CharField

Tags: django

If have the following Django (1.4) model:

```
from django.db import models

class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And this simple test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from models import SimpleModel
from django.db import IntegrityError

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_integrity_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            m = SimpleModel()
            m.save()
```

As database a sqlite3 database is used. If I now run the tests with `python manage.py test <appname>` the test fails with `AssertionError: IntegrityError not raised`.

The question is: **why?**

As far as I understand (or thought to understand) Django the default values for Fields are `blank=False` and `null=False` so I would assume that saving an model instance with the default value (which I think for a CharField should be an empty string) should certainly fail! So, why doesn't this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django never stores NULL for empty `CharField` or `TextField` types. It stores an empty string (`''`). So that's why you don't get an `IntegrityError` for `null=False`.

As for `blank=False`, that only affects forms. It just makes the form set the field as `required=True` so it won't validate unless it has a value. It doesn't affect the database or your ability to manually set a blank value outside of a form.