# Disallow non-blank values for certain model fields

Tags: django

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848162/django-tests-dont-raise-integrity-error-for-charfield) I would like to know if there is way to make sure, that a model instance can not be persisted if there are any field with `blank=False` that have blank value. I.e. if I have this model:

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to disallow something like:

```
m = SimpleModel()
m.save()
```

I could do this by overriding `save()` and do the check manually, but maybe there is another way.

The reason for this is that I want to make really, really sure that such blank values are never inserted into the database (in case me or some of my co-coders go mad).

Answer (score 0):

This is what [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) is for. You need to ensure you run `m.full_clean()` before save.