# How to check if not providing a value for a specific field when instantiating a model is going to cause an error?

Tags: django, django-testing

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

>>> User._meta.get_field("username").null
False
```

But

```
>>> user()
<User: >
```

Wth? I expected an `IntegrityError` because a `null` value isn't allowed to be stored in the database with `null=False`.

Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848162/django-tests-dont-raise-integrity-error-for-charfield):

> Django never stores NULL for empty CharField or TextField types. It
>   stores an empty string (''). So that's why you don't get an
>   IntegrityError for null=False.

Ow ok, that must mean there is an empty string defined as the default value right?

> > > User._meta.get_field("username").default
> > >       django.db.models.fields.NOT_PROVIDED

What? I expected an empty string ... .

Then how are you supposed to check (e.g. for usage in tests, with `assertEquals`/`assertRaise`/...) if not providing a value for a specific field (e.g. `username`) when instantiating a model (e.g. `User`) 
is going to cause an exception?

### Edit

I would like to know how someone would write a unit test to check this. (If `assertNotRaises` existed it would have been easier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`full_clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method.

```
>>> User().full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 950, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'username': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'password': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}
```

Comment: You are checking if ValidationErrors are being raised, that is if 
`User._meta.get_field("username").blank` is `False`. I'm asking about if `User._meta.get_field("username").null` is `False` however.